# Force login after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

im using cake php 2.4 my problem is sometimes after session idle, or logout in other tab the ajax request doesn't work because the user is already  logged out.
my question is how i can verify that to redirect the user to the login page.
my function that im using to filter requests is used on my userscontroller class

```
//class UsersController
public function beforefilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();

        // Allow users to  logout.
        $this->Auth->allow('logout');
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    // redirect here
}
```

Comment: but im using ajax request , so it won't work , her's a link i found but it didn't work for me http://adrianharding.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/cakephp-jquery-redirect-on-logout-over-ajax/. im using cakkephp 2.x

Comment: What does ajax have to do with it?  You're still in a Controller when determining their logged-in status, right?

Comment: no, im using the plupload plugin that give the possiblity to do multiple upload with ajax it works very well, but sometimes when the user leave the machine for a while the upload don't work because of the session idle so i want to manage that situation by redirecting the user to the login page or displaying a message  to him that he hase to log in, so in the controller i have to verify if it's ajax request and send back an ajax response to user to refirect him with window.location but i don't know how and where to put that code

Comment: I understood what you were asking the first time - my answer is the same.  Your ajax still has to hit some aspect of you're PHP code.  In it, check if they're logged in and handle accordingly.

Comment: after searching and testing i have found what's the problem is, it's in the $this->request->is('ajax') it gives me false in the beforefilter when im using fileupload with ajax , so with your code for testing session invalidation works